# Remove trailing 0 when CAST as NVarChar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have data as `Decimal(15,4)` and values can be like `14.0100`, or `14.0000`, or `14.9999`

For integration with other system we have to store this kind of data in `NVarChar(MAX)` attributes table. When I run `CAST(Field AS NVarChar(MAX))` I get string values like `0.0000`

What I want is to trim trailing zeros (and period if needed) from those strings because data later used in online transmission and it's much better to send `14` instead of `14.0000`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SQL Server 2012+` you could use `FORMAT`, with `SQL Server 2008` you could use string manipulation:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(col DECIMAL(15,4));

INSERT INTO #tab(col)
VALUES (14.0100), (14.0000),
       (14.9999), (10), (0),
       (-1), (-10), (-12.01), (-12.10);

SELECT 
  col
 ,result_2012 = FORMAT(col, '########.####') 
 ,result_2008 = CASE 
                 WHEN col = 0 THEN '0'
                 ELSE LEFT(col,LEN(col) - 
                        CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', REVERSE(col)) < PATINDEX('%[.]%', REVERSE(col))
                             THEN PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', REVERSE(col)) - 1 
                             ELSE PATINDEX('%[.]%', REVERSE(col))
                        END)
               END
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/423185)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You could try casting the Decimal numbers to floats before casting then casting them to `NVarChars i.e. CAST(CAST(Field as Float(8)) as NVarChar(MAX)).`  The only issue you might have with this is if any of your existing numbers have a greater precision than an 8 byte float can deal with which should be easy enough to check for.

It would also be possible to remove the extra zeros after you've casted the numbers as strings using case statements, i.e.

```
case when right(Field, 4) = '0000' then
 left(Field, len(Field) - 5) -- -5 to remove the decimal point
else case when right(Field, 3) = '000' Then
 left(Field, len(Field) - 3)
else case when right(Field, 2) = '00' Then
 left(Field, len(Field) - 2)
else case when right(Field, 1) = '0' Then
 left(Field, len(Field) - 1)
end end end end
```

Comment: I like `Float(8)` idea, what is max precision? Some decimals we use are(18,15)

Comment: I think if you use float(53) it can in theory be used for up to 15 digits, but due to the nature of the way they're stored they aren't always 100% precise.  You could try a select * from table where field <> cast(field as float(53)) to see if there are any numbers it doesn't convert accurately.

Comment: `FLOAT` is inaccurate datatype. Mixing it with exact datatype (DECIMAL) is not best idea.

Comment: Yes, I will check. Per documentation `Float` is 53 by default. But I remember I've seen weird conversions before, I never use Float in my code..

Comment: If you have decimals with different precision and accuracy is important a better way of going about it might be to write a recursive function that keeps checking and removing the last character of a string until it doesn't equal '0'.

Comment: lad2025 posted nice solution but removed it. I guess because of `0.0000` case :)

Comment: @katit Now it handles other cases but it isn't so nice as prev version :)

Comment: @katit [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/423581) Scientific notation when you use `CAST(CAST(Field as Float(8)) as NVarChar(MAX)).` with bigger number + possible lost of precision

Answer (score 0):

```
--With a lot of fantasy
--Tip: to optimize performances, first select values in a @-table, then do this transformation.
select 
left( cast(Field  as varchar(max)), charindex('.', cast(Field  as varchar(max))) - 1) + 
Case when reverse(cast(cast(reverse(substring(cast(Field  as varchar), charindex('.', cast(Field  as varchar)) + 1 ,4)) as int) as nvarchar)) = 0 Then '' Else
'.' + reverse(cast(cast(reverse(substring(cast(Field  as varchar), charindex('.', cast(Field  as varchar)) + 1 ,4)) as int) as nvarchar)) End
```

Comment: This returns 14.10, 14.0, 14.9999

Comment: Right. I forgot a reverse. Now is correct (if 14.0 is expected value).

Comment: No, needs to be 14, not 14.0

Comment: Edited. Now selects 14. Bye

Answer (score 0):

simple casting to REAL then back to varch(max) if you want will remove the leading 0s as follows:

```
declare @a as Decimal(15,4)=14.0010
select cast(cast (@a as real) as varchar(max)) as a2
-- ouptut is 14.001
declare @a as Decimal(15,4)=14.0000
select cast(cast (@a as real) as varchar(max)) as a2
-- output is 14
```

Comment: **As always simple and not entirely correct:** `declare @a as Decimal(15,4)=1000014.0010
select cast(cast (@a as real) as varchar(max)) as a2` **[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/423583)** Result **1.00001e+006**

Comment: nice tip @lad ... I have made another "simple" and correct Answer, kindly review it below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Idea here is to use the built in string function of Trimming spaces to TRIM ZEROs from the converted decimal as follows:

```
declare @d as Decimal(15,4)=11400012.00000, @s0 VARCHAR(MAX), @s VARCHAR(MAX)
set @s0=cast(@d as varchar(max))
set @s=left(@s0,len(rtrim(replace(@s0,'0',' '))))
if right(@s,1)='.' set @s=left(@s,len(@s)-1)
select @s
-- returns 11400012.001
```

You also can define the function to do this task for you:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TRIM0(@s0 varchar(max))
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @s varchar(max)=''
    set @s=left(@s0,len(rtrim(replace(@s0,'0',' '))))
    if right(@s,1)='.' set @s=left(@s,len(@s)-1)
    return @s
END
```

Comment: As always almost simple but not entirely correct  Don't get me wrong. It is very good you try to be helpful, but please do basic test before you post your solution. Counter example: **`11400000.0000` -> `114`**. **[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/423691)**

Comment: @lad did you check how simple solutions could be correct!! :)

Comment: Yes it is very convinent to write custom UDF for Ad-hoc queries :). All your simple solution needs to be wrapped by function, how would you use it for multiple rows at once without UDF? Anyway simple solution is to upgrade to decent version of SQL Server and use built-in `FORMAT`